# AWS GuardDuty: "There was a problem fetching your GuardDuty detector ID"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-guardduty

I want to use AWS GuardDuty for a project but I get this error each time I want to access it:

> There was a problem fetching your GuardDuty detector ID. Please refresh the page in your browser.

What might the cause of this error?

Comment: Are you using control tower?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers.

**Solution-1:**
After enabling and configuring MFA for your user account then Log out and login your AWS account. For sure it works.

**Solution-2:**
You will see the "403" response code when your AWS account tries to connect to the guard duty service using this API: hxxps://guardduty.eu-nxxxx-1.amazonaws.com/detector. This code indicates that the request may be prohibited due to insufficient permission. I'll advise you to get in touch with your internal AWS administrator to get the official permission to access AWS services.